# Recovering dogecoin wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet.dat, dogecoin

My brother and I had some dogecoins from way back.  He reformatted his hard drive at least once, maybe twice.

I have no hope in recovering them but I am going to try.  People are telling me to not even bother turning the computer on to use a program like Recuva or whatever.  They're telling me to keep it turned off and create an image of the hard drive.

I have no idea how to go about data recovery in a smart way.  If anyone has any advice it would be greatly appreciated.  If anyone has a data recovery company that is actually trustworthy and would likely not bone me, that would be great as well.  But I would like to approach this on my own if possible.